# Is my text mangled beyond repair?

Tags: text-processing, unicode, character-encoding

My mangled Czech text:

```
NOTE ON CZECH BIRTH NUMBER VALIDATION IN CZECH LANGUAGE;
in Czechia birth number = personal identification number
========================================================
Do roku 1985 bylo pé?idá?leno cca 1000 rodnű§ch á?űŮsel, kterűŔ nejsou dá?litelnűŔ 11.
NenűŮ vylouá?eno, éƒe se v miniműŔlnűŮm poá?tu vyskytly i po tomto roce.
KorektnűŮ algoritmus je nűŔsledujűŮcűŮ:
spoá?ti zbytek po dá?lenűŮ prvnűŮch devűŮti á?űŮslic a á?űŮsla 11; je-li zbytek 10, musűŮ bű§t poslednűŮ á?űŮslice 0; jinak poslednűŮ á?űŮslice musűŮ bű§t rovna zbytku; Tedy 780123/3540 je korektnűŮ rodnű? á?űŮslo, aá?koliv nenűŮ dá?litelnű? jedenűŔcti.
```

Last two words spelled correctly: **dá?litelnű? jedenűŔcti = dělitelné jedenácti**.

---

I found a FTFY tool https://ftfy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ but even with it I could not fix the text.

It ought to be UTF-8 with BOM, and I tried removing the BOM using VI; reloading my text with Sublime Text to every possible encoding.

So my thinking is, this text may have lost some piece of information which makes it impossible to repair now?

It would be a pity as I have much more of the text.

---

Notes:

- No, I do not have any previous *unmangled* texts, not sure how it happened either.
- `set | grep -E '^LC_|^LANG'`:

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LANGUAGE=en_US
LC_ADDRESS=en_US.UTF-8
LC_IDENTIFICATION=en_US.UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8
LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8
LC_NAME=en_US.UTF-8
LC_NUMERIC=en_US.UTF-8
LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8
LC_TELEPHONE=en_US.UTF-8
LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8
```

Should there be somewhere `cs_CZ`? Just a rant...

- `file MainWindow.xaml.cs`:

```
MainWindow.xaml.cs: C++ source, Unicode text, UTF-8 text
```

- `od -t ax1 MainWindow.xaml.cs`: very large output, will shrink it once I get back from a funeral.
- `LC_ALL=cs_CZ.UTF-8 head -50 '/mnt/windows/Users/vlastimil/Downloads/_DISK_D/csharp/Rodné číslo a IČ/Rodné číslo a IČ/MainWindow.xaml.cs' | grep jeden`

```
Tedy 780123/3540 je korektnűŮ rodnű? á?űŮslo, aá?koliv nenűŮ dá?litelnű? jedenűŔcti.
```

`LC_ALL=cs_CZ.UTF-8 head -50 '/mnt/windows/Users/vlastimil/Downloads/_DISK_D/csharp/Rodné číslo a IČ/Rodné číslo a IČ/MainWindow.xaml.cs' | grep jeden | od -t ax1`

```
0000000   T   e   d   y  sp   7   8   0   1   2   3   /   3   5   4   0
         54  65  64  79  20  37  38  30  31  32  33  2f  33  35  34  30
0000020  sp   j   e  sp   k   o   r   e   k   t   n   E   1   E   .  sp
         20  6a  65  20  6b  6f  72  65  6b  74  6e  c5  b1  c5  ae  20
0000040   r   o   d   n   E   1   ?  sp   C   !   ?   E   1   E   .   s
         72  6f  64  6e  c5  b1  3f  20  c3  a1  3f  c5  b1  c5  ae  73
0000060   l   o   ,  sp   a   C   !   ?   k   o   l   i   v  sp   n   e
         6c  6f  2c  20  61  c3  a1  3f  6b  6f  6c  69  76  20  6e  65
0000100   n   E   1   E   .  sp   d   C   !   ?   l   i   t   e   l   n
         6e  c5  b1  c5  ae  20  64  c3  a1  3f  6c  69  74  65  6c  6e
0000120   E   1   ?  sp   j   e   d   e   n   E   1   E dc4   c   t   i
         c5  b1  3f  20  6a  65  64  65  6e  c5  b1  c5  94  63  74  69
0000140   .  nl
         2e  0a
0000142
```

having no idea what the above means however, sorry for the delay.

Comment: Run something like `od -t ax1` over the file and locate some of the question marks. If they are real ascii question marks rather than just replacement characters of whatever tool you load the file into, then file is most likely doomed.

Comment: @Harald I am back for a brief moment, have posted an example if such a thing can be considered as one.

Comment: You probably copypasted the text after the `echo`, which causes it to loose the original encoding (the `?` is now really a `?` and not an unprintable character). You can use `head`, `tail`, `less` etc. to extract the "dělitelné jedenácti" part from the `od` dump.

Comment: @dirkt You are correct, I indeed copy-pasted it. Will use direct method as you are suggesting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Partial answer, to explain the process:

From the hexdump, one can see that in the "korektnűŮ rodnű?" part, the bytes "c5  b1  c5  ae" are the end of "korektnűŮ", and the bytes "c5  b1  3f" are the end of "rodnű?". And the `?` is really a `?`.

If "ű?" in "rodnű?" should really be a "é" as in "dá?litelnű?" -> "dělitelné", then we now know that somehow the "é" ended up as "c5  b1  3f". But I don't know Czech, so I don't know if this is correct.

Then now we can start guessing what happened. "c5 b1" looks like a two byte character encoding, so my **guess** is that this text was converted twice for some reason - the first step had "é" encoded as two bytes (in whatever encoding), then the second step encoded the first byte as "c5  b1", while the second byte was unprintable, and it ended up as a `?`.

That is unfortunate, because if that is true, then we lost the information about the unprintable bytes. Still, there may be enough information to reconstruct the text if there are not too many letters that ended up as "c5  b1  3f".

But the step before that is to know gather enough data - we need enough "letter é got converted to c5  b1  3f" examples for the different accented letters to either guess through which two encodings the text got mangled.

Or, if we cannot guess that, maybe you can already detect enough pairs that we can just replace the mangled byte sequences with the correct letters, without having to reconstruct the mangling process.

But we need you as a Czech speaker to do that, because you have the whole text, and you can guess the right letters.